# jQuery .load() not working

Tags: jquery, url, html, dns, load

On my website, I'm trying to pull the content of a post in my forum (hosted on the same domain) and display it in a div on the homepage, using jQuery.

Here's the code for the header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery("#contain").load("http://examplepage.com/forum/showthread.php?tid=NN #pid_NN");
</script>
```

Then, there's the div I'd like to display the post:

```
<div id="contain"></div>
```

Things to consider:

- The library loads just fine.
- If I enter any other code, it works (like testing alert(1);).
- The console doesn't report any errors.
- The div stays blank; in fact, it doesn't even show. It is there, though.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Remove the space before the # in your URL. What do your console say?

Comment: Do you really have a space there: `tid=NN #pid_NN`?

Comment: Remove http:// examplepage.com

Comment: The space is supposed to be there, read the manual for load()

Comment: The space actually gets the right element from the returned data, and is totally valid.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? The OP shows every sign of having made an effort and clearly describes the problem.

Comment: Are you making a cross-domain call via ajax?

Comment: `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js` needs to be `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js`

Comment: @KD: Not according to the question: *"...pull the content of a post in my forum (hosted on the same domain)..."*

Comment: @s.lenders `//` is fine. It means use the same protocol as the page, whether it be `http://` or `https://`

Comment: @s.lenders: No, it doesn't. By leaving off the protocol, you make the `script` tag friendly to both `http` and `https`. More: [*Skipping the protocol*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/skipping-protocol.html)

Comment: @sjdaws well then explain why i've use that before and then jQuery libary doesn't get loaded

Comment: are you sure about dom ready

Comment: @s.lenders - you probably did it on a local server. `//` works fine, and is recommended by Google!

Comment: @s.lenders: It wouldn't work if you loaded the HTML file directly, e.g., from a `file:` protocol. Other than that, it works.

Comment: Add a callback handler. Something like `alert( "page was called to." );` and check if it is being fired or not.

Comment: Well nothing tells he doesn't does it?

Comment: Thanks everyone, the issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

your code should be something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
```

js code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
       jQuery("#contain").load("http://examplepage.com/forum/showthread.php?tid=NN #pid_NN");
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Actually, the second part of this is a possibility. @TW_, is your `script` tag **after** your `div` in the HTML? If not, move it there (or use `ready` as above, but that's really not necessary if you control where your `script` tag goes).

Comment: Sweet!
Thanks a lot; it never occurred to me that jquery itself needed to be invoked separately. I'm new to this stuff. :)
Consider the answer accepted in a few minutes.

Comment: @TW_: jQuery **doesn't** need to be "invoked" separately. What the `ready` above does is delay execution of your `load` until all of the HTML has been parsed and the DOM elements created. Your code was running before the `div` was created, and so jQuery couldn't find the `div` (as it didn't exist yet). While you *can* use `ready` to handle that, if you're in control of where your `script` tag goes, it's better to just put it at the bottom of the page, just before the `</body>` tag, and not use `ready`. The `div` will exist then. That's what both Google and Yahoo recommend.

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(function(){});
was a reminder. thumps up

Answer (score 1):

`.load` can pass your GET params seperate:

```
.load("link to php", "http://examplepage.com/forum/showthread.php", "tid=NN#pid_NN")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a closing `</script>` tag on your jQuery include, and you need to wait for dom load.

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery("#contain").load("http://examplepage.com/forum/showthread.php?tid=NN#pid_NN");
    });
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div id="contain"></div>
```

Comment: You don't *need* to use `ready`. You can just put the `script` tag doing the `load` **after** the `div`. And in fact, that's the better approach. `ready` is really only for code where you don't control where the `script` tag goes.

Answer (score -1):

Check this code. you should use ">*" after container id to load content specific container on the page.

```
jQuery('#contain').load("http://example.com/pageurl #somecontaineronpage >*",function(){
      //after loading completion code goes here                      
});
```

Hope, this will help