# Using jQuery Load Function before DOM Ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a page that renders HTML blocks from another page on the same domain using IDs.  My current code:

```
<div id=”testdiv”></div>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
   jQuery('#testdiv').load('/references/embed1.html #testdiv2'); 
});
</script>
```

While this loads the content correctly, there is a visible lag between the page loading and the jQuery content loading; depending on the DIV contents it sometimes a full second to display then it just pops into place.  This is obviously due to the page not attempting to retrieve the HTML content until DOM Ready so I removed the ready function but the Load function doesn’t run.  If I use an iFrame instead it appears to load as the browser executes the code but I lose the ability to only include specific DIV IDs and it’s difficult to make it responsive.  Looked at $.ajax but apparently Load uses .ajax so it doesn’t look like there will be a difference.

Simply put – how do I load specific DIV ids from another page without waiting for DOM Ready whether jQuery, JavaScript, iFrames or other method?  Second question

Thanks

Comment: simple... remove `jQuery(document).ready(function(){`. It should work fine *if your code is **exactly** as it is in your question*. note however there will likely still be a delay, one that you can't remove other than by removing the need to use ajax to get this content in the first place.

Comment: Why the down vote?  I stated removing the dom ready didn't work for me.  Furthermore, this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15107074/jquery-load-not-working states the same problem and the resolution is DOM ready.

Comment: Updated comment above.  Downvoting thereby indicating I haven't done any research when my OP stated I have and others here on SE have the same issue (basically what you suggest _should_ work but doesn't) isn't accurate.

Comment: well, no. the question is not useful. it states that the solution doesn't work, when it in fact does, and doesn't provide proof otherwise.

Comment: `$(document).ready` is only needed if you're code is executed before the element in the dom. Your example shows the opposite of that, therefore it should work just fine without it.

Answer (score 1):

`document ready`will be triggered until the whole page were loaded, just remove it and `.load()` will be invoked after `#testdiv` had finish render on DOM.
here's the example

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<div id="testdiv"></div>
<div id="error"></div>

<script>
$( "#testdiv" ).load( "/references/embed1.html #testdiv2", function( response, status, xhr ) {
  alert("Triggered");
  if ( status == "error" ) {
    var msg = "Err trying to load ";
    $( "#error" ).html( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
  }
});
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Angel_xMu/rer3yuny/1/

Answer (score -4):

Ajax is not instant, and nothing you do will change that. Therefore, there will always be some form of delay. You can reduce the delay by removing the need for `$(document).ready()`, however I suspect it still won't be enough to have it do what you were hoping for.

```
$.get('page.html', function (result) {
  // note, you may need to use `.filter` rather than `.find` depending on the structure of `result`
  $('#target').html($($.parseHTML(result)).find('#target2'));
});
```

or leave your code as is minus `$(document).ready` and move it to after the target div just like in your example.

The only way to completely remove the delay would be to remove the need for using `$.ajax` by inserting the html directly into the page server-side.