# jQuery .load() not loading HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a script that imports my site's header into each page. I have already seen these pages:

- [jQuery .load() not working - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15107074/9549259)
- [.load() - jQuery API Docs](https://api.jquery.com/load/)

I followed these sites, and I still get this error in the console:

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: Object doesn't support property or method 'load' 
TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'load'
   at Anonymous function (http://localhost/header-footer.js:4:5)
   at l (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2:29559)
   at Anonymous function (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2:29869) undefined
```

My `index.html` has the following in the `body` section:

```
<div id="header"></div>
<script src="..." integrity="..." crossorigin="anonymous"></script> <!--jQuery-->
<script src="/header-footer.js"></script> <!--Shown below-->
```

The `header-footer.js` file includes:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var header = $("#header");
    header.addClass("container-fluid clearfix"); // Bootstrap classes (unrelated as far as I know)
    header.load("/header.html");
});
```

I would just like to be able to import my `header.html` file into my `index.html` file.

I don't think this is related to the error, but here are the contents of my `header.html` file:

```
<ul class="list-inline">
    <li>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="dropdownButton">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="...">Another page</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a class="btn btn-primary" href="/" role="button">Home</a></li>
    <li class="lead" style="float: left;">Website Name</li>
</ul>
<hr>
```

What silly mistake have I made? Thank you!

Comment: You're using jquery slim. Is that correct? Try to use https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js instead of slim version.

Comment: Glad to hear @RenanAraújo helped. You can also see here for other differences between jQuery and jQuery slim: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35424053

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using jquery slim.

Use code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js instead of slim version to use `load` method.