# html page doesn't load in Div using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm trying to load Html page on click on a link , but for some reason it doesn't work at all .
this is my LogIn.HTML page :

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#game1").click(function(){
        $("#result1").load('Game.html');
    });
    $("#players").click(function(){
        $("#result1").load('players.html');
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
  <td><a  id="game1"  href="" style="color:white;">Game</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><a href="" id="players"  style="color:white;">players</a></td>
  </tr>

  </table>

<div  id="result1" >
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

AND this is my basic Game.html (the Players.html same concept):

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
  <h1>this is first game!!!</h1>
  </head>
</html>
```

i've tried many solutions but i can't make it work , also i open the html page using chrome (not localhost,regular one) does it affects ?

Comment: Prefix `#` with id selector i.e. `$("#game1")` instead of `$("game1")`

Comment: hi , i've updated the post i added the # tag it still doesnt' work

Comment: @ you are missing `#game1 and #players` and make sure load(); path is correct.

Answer (score 2):

You could try moving the script tag to the bottom: as suggested in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15107074/jquery-load-not-working)

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><a id="game1" href="" style="color:white;">Game</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="" id="players" style="color:white;">players</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="result1"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#game1").click(function(){
                $("#result1").load('https://full/path/to/Game.html');
            });
            $("#players").click(function(){
                $("#result1").load('https://full/path/to/players.html');
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Update:**

- Plus you missed a `#` in `"game1"`, corrected in the above example.
- Corrected the html in `#game1` as pointed out in the comments

Comment: hi , thank you for the help , but still didn't affect anything

Comment: I'm not the downvoter but I know it: 1/. You don't have `</head>` tag. 2/. The script at the bottom is outside `body` tag. 3/. The code is not formatted.

Comment: Your answer, unlike one that was posted before it, didn't correct the OP's errors in the id selectors.

Comment: @Nelson Owalo In your code HTML `id=#game1` remove `#`

Comment: Sigh. Yes, you edited it after, but then added an extra # on an id declaration. A slower, more accurate answer is better than a lightning-fast one with errors. Downvote rescinded, anyhow.

Comment: @peeebeee Thanks alot, I cant believe I missed that

Comment: `href=""` add `#`, i.e. `href="#"`. empty string command to page refresh.

Comment: You are loading the model using either `file://` or `C:/`, you can see error message as they are not `http://`.  So you can either install a webserver in your local PC or upload the code somewhere

Answer (score 1):

Your code `$("game1")` and `$("players")` is missing the # tag identifier for ID's.
It should be `$("#game1")` and `$("#players")`.,

So

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#game1").click(function(){
        $("#result1").load('Game.html');
    });
    $("#players").click(function(){
        $("#result1").load('players.html');
    });
});
```

Also you've place the `<h1>` element inside the `<head>` tag. If you wish to see a result you should have the following inside the Game.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>this is first game!!!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Also make sure that the file is in the same directory as the LogIn.html page.

I also believe you need to specify which element you want to include otherwise all the html might get loaded into the element. So maybe your code should be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#game1").click(function(){
        $("#result1").load('Game.html #body');
    });
    $("#players").click(function(){
        $("#result1").load('players.html #body');
    });
});
```

Comment: hi , i've updated the post i added the # tag it still doesnt' work

Comment: If you expecting to see the `<h1>this is first game!!!</h1>` element, you won't because you've placed it in the <head> tag. You should have it in the body. Let me update my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can easily modify your current `<a>` tag for this kind of action with a link, its easier and also faster. For example, change your `<a>` tag and include in it href, like this:

```
<a id="game1"  href="./Game.html" style="color:white;">Game</a>
```

And here you see the second problem. You are referencing the file wrong. To call out a file, you need to show in what folder its in. In this case "./" means in the current folder your main index.html file is.

If you still want to stick with JQuery for this action, then here is a fix for you (provided if you have your Game.html and Players.html in the **same folder** as your main index.html file)

```
$("#game1").click(function(){
        $("#result1").load('./Game.html');
    });
    $("#players").click(function(){
        $("#result1").load('./players.html');
    });
```

Also, be mindful that the file references are case sensitive. In your description you wrote that you need to load **P**layers.html, but in code youre trying to load **p**layers.html.

Comment: and yeah, like @Nelson Owalo said, move your script after the html body elements declaration, so it actually finds the elements to click on.

Comment: hi , i have to use the div idea and not move to another HTML page , i've tried what you said and still doesn't work

Comment: Take a look at your most upvoted answer from @Nelson Owalo about the file path. Also, Met-U noted that your heading tag is in <head> which is wrong. And lastly, it wasn't a DIV idea, please dont use href inside a DIV element.